# Redirecionamento de URL em IIS

Tags: iis, redirecionamento

Estou tendo problemas com redirecionamento aqui na empresa, é o seguinte:

Tenho um servidor **IIS** onde tenho o site atual da empresa e dentro deste site tenho *webservices* rodando, utilizando um dominio `???.com.br` na porta 80.

Minha dúvida é que contratei uma empresa para criar um novo site e o site da minha empresa vai ficar em um subdomínio desta empresa que contratei e gostaria que quando alguém digitar `www.???.com.br` (meu domínio) ele seja redirecionado para o subdomínio da empresa que contratei para desenvolver o novo site, problema maior é que ao digitar o meu domínio o usuário vai ter que vir no meu IIS para depois ser redirecionado, pois não posso redirecionar meu domínio para o subdomínio da empresa que fez o novo site pois tenho os meus *webservices* rodando no mesmo domínio `www.???.com.br`

Alguém pode me dar uma luz de como resolver este problema? Meio confusa a explicação mais acho que deu pra entender.

Answer (score 0):

Há muitas formas de se fazer o redirecionamento para outra página, independente delas estarem no mesmo domínio.

1) Se seu domínio apontar para uma página HTML, por exemplo, você pode incluir a tag meta abaixo dentro do  `head`:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;http://subdominio.dominio.com.br">`

Provavelmente é o melhor método, pois é simples e funciona mesmo que o browser cliente esteja com o Javascript desabilitado.

2) Você pode redirecionar utilizando Javascript:

```
<script language=javascript>
    function redirect(){
        window.location.href = "http://subdominio.dominio.com.br";
    }
</script>

<body onload="redirect()">
    <!-- Qualquer conteúdo no body não será exibido, uma vez que a página será redirecionada -->
</body>
```

3) Se a página for ASP você pode utilizar:

`<% Response.Redirect ("http://subdominio.dominio.com.br") %>`

4) Se a página for PHP você pode utilizar:

`<?php header('location: http://subdominio.dominio.com.br');`

Dentre outras formas.